# Can requestAnimationFrame be called from input events and still respect refresh rate?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, webgl

I want to optimize redraws in my WebGL application. A redraw is only needed, when the user modifies the camera position or rotation. Everything else is static. I can keep calling `requestAnimationFrame()` with the classic js game loop, check for changes to the camera and only redraw if needed.

```js
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if (compare_camera_with_previous_frame()) {
        render();
    }
}
```

This works and the GPU only does drawing when the a redraw is really needed. However, this still marks my WebApp as animated, requestAnimationFrame() is called 60 times a second, doing essentially nothing except check for a change in the game state.

Another option is to remove `requestAnimationFrame(animate);` from `animate()` loop and call `requestAnimationFrame(animate);` from the touch event. However, this leads to drawing happening at hundreds of FPS, as `animate()` is being called on each touch event.

In C with DesktopGL and SDL2 or with GLFW I am used to call [`WaitEvents()`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga554e37d781f0a997656c26b2c56c835e) instead of [`PollEvents()`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga37bd57223967b4211d60ca1a0bf3c832). With V-Sync on, this solves everything perfectly. Logic being processed only when an input is performed, whilst not exceeding refresh rate. I want to translate such a behavior into Javascript + WebGL.

How can I solve this? How to only request frames to be drawn when events happen, yet not exceed the refresh rate set by `requestAnimationFrame();` being called in a loop?

Comment: "doing essentially nothing except check for a change in the game state" so, doing exactly what it should be doing. `requestAnimationFrame` does what the name suggests: it request an execution callback on the next available frame. If you wrote your requestAnimationFrame correctly, you're _not_ running at hundreds of frames per second, your animation loop runs at "your monitor's framerate" (or slower, if you do a lot of work per frame). You have _one_ requestAnimationFrame loop, and you make that check the current state, with events updating that state, not scheduling animation calls themselves.

Comment: Ture. But the state cannot change without user input. Meaning, that the act of checking the state 60 times a second is useless. It can only change on user input. This is what I want to optimize away and solve.
(it actually does run properly at 60fps, but I don't need a loop in the first place if input isn't touched)

Comment: Why? What _actual_ problem are you experiencing with a core loop that checks for a state change (you _are_ remembering to mark your state as updated when you change it, and unmark it after running a full frame, right? Don't run state comparisons, just set a "dumb" boolean to true as part of setting state values, and set that it back to false at the end of the frame handling code) and do nothing that frame if the update flag isn't set? If would be _amazing_ if that overhead made any kind of measurable difference compared to the rest of the code =)

Comment: Everything runs as expected and I do reset the state check properly. There is no performance difference. Performance is not the goal, but battery savings. Not calling `requestAnimationFrame()` allows the app to become a static webpage, with the browser going idle and the device entering deep sleep. This is what I want to achive. This is what *I have* achived by calling `animate()` directly from events. But doing that does not respect the refresh rate as stated above.

Comment: Then literally do that: don't call a next requestAnimationFrame the moment your state no longer has updates, so that your animation loop halts and your page becomes a static page. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop running your animation loop if there's nothing to animate:

```js
function animate() {
  // return early if there's nothing to do, halting the animation loop:
  if (!state.stateUpdated) return;

  // soft-lock our state so that values will get written to
  // our "pending state" object instead of the real state, to
  // prevent concurrent modification.
  pendingState = {};

  // then resolve a frame:
  doSomethingThisFrame();

  // and then apply any pending state changes that
  // occurred while we were busy during the frame.
  applyPendingStateChanges();
}

function doSomethingThisFrame() { 
  // ...do all the things...

  // mark the state as handled:
  state.stateUpdated = false;

  // and schedule the next frame:
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

And then you can set that flag to to true and then call `animate()` as part of updating the state during during input event etc. so that your code will start to run again for as long as there's something to animate. And the moment there isn't, that early return will revert the page to a static page again.

Of course, you'll want to make sure that you're not concurrently updating state *while* you're busy work on a frame, so you'll want to make sure to have a "pending state" variable that can both act as soft lock, and that you can write values to while the real state is locked:

```
const state = { stateUpdated: false };
let pendingState = undefined;

function updateState(name, value) {
  // apply this update either directly, or "for later":
  const target = pendingState ?? state;
  target[name] = value;
  target.stateUpdated = true;
  // and if we applied it directly, call animate.
  if (target === state) animate();
}

function applyPendingStateChanges() {
  if (!pendingState) throw new Error(`apply pending called without pending state`);
  Object.assign(state, pendingState);
  pendingState = undefined;
  if (state.stateUpdated) animate();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The 'stopping the animation loop' point is an important thought I missed so far. I will try that out and report on success. One thing still doesn't click in my head though. I have a function `checkIfStateUpdated()`. And many events (touch, keyboard, mouse, mousewheel) potentially updating the state at almost 1000hz.  If I do `stateUpdated = false` right after `if (!stateUpdated) return;`, then what purpose does `requestAnimationFrame()` even serve? Or rather: When should `checkIfStateUpdated()` happen, when should `stateUpdated = false` happen? That is what I failed to grasp so far.

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure why, but it appears to work. Gotta stare at logic for a bit to understand why.

Comment: It worked! One *very* confusing thing, that had me tripped up though... I have implemented this and measured the FPS and how often `if (!stateUpdated) return;` is entered. Both are at refresh rate. Equal parts rendered equal parts rejected. *Except* on Chrome + Edge, *only* if the dev console is open. Then, the rejected mouse events explode to 1000hz. It does not happen in Firefox and is the reason why I was so confused as to if you may call requestAnimationFrame() often or not. `Controls->Settings->Debug` at [mirror.frost.kiwi](https://mirror.frost.kiwi) in case you want to see the numbers.

Comment: If you're seeing `animate()` run that line _that much_, your code needs to stop calling `animate()` _unless_ the state isn't already marked as updated (i.e. you update the state but you _only_ make that update call `animate` if that flag is false) and you need to make sure to unset it as the very last thing `doSomethingThisFrame()` does. It's your lock variable. Basically, don't make your events set things themselves, have a dedicated `updateState(name, value)` function and only have _that_ update your state and your lock.

Comment: Specifically, if I read into your `If I do stateUpdated = false right after if (!stateUpdated) return;, then what [...]` comment, you're currently setting `stateUpdated` to false _way_ too early. You only set it to false after you do everything that needs to happen that frame, as the very last thing you do. And even then, you can only do that safely if your state updates are batched and then not applied until your frame has finished handling. Let me update the answer to cover this, because it sounds like you didn't take that into account.

Comment: Wanted give big thanks, this really helped with my [WebApp](https://mirrorball.frost.kiwi/) to properly implement resource friendly redraws. Credited you in the repo: https://github.com/FrostKiwi/Mirrorball

Comment: Would be happy to somehow make GitHub credit you as a contributor, not just the Readme mention.

Comment: I didn't contribute to your project, I just helped you figure out a problem. No need to treat it as more than that =)